# Quickest way to create a CountableClosedRange<Int> that has a distance between values of more than 1

Tags: swift

I want to create a `CountableClosedRange<Int>` for a for loop. Normally I'd do this:

```
for i in 0...10 {
    print(i)
}
```

But I want it to go 30, 60, 90 etc in multiples of 30. What's the quick way to do that? Do I have to do it like this:

```
var i = 30
while i <= 120 {
    print(i)
    i += 30
}
```

Or is there a more "swifty" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`stride`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride):

```
for i in stride(from: 0, through: 120, by: 30) {

}
```